# Input data validation in CakePHP REST API

Tags: php, api, validation, rest, cakephp

I am developing a REST API using CakePHP. The problem is regarding the validation of data that is sent as input parameters to my API. In the [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) they have mentioned [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html). But how do I implement it for a REST API?

I want that if I add a validation something like this in `app/Model/Table.php`:

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => 'email'
);
```

Then when I user makes the request `myapi.com/resource?email=abc123` I want the API to respond like

`status: 400`

```
{
    "message": "Invalid Parameter",
    "url": "/resource"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html), in the controller you can use:

```
$this->Model->set($this->request->data);

if (!$this->Model->validates()) {
    $this->response->statusCode(400);
    $this->set('_serialize', array(
       'message' => 'Invalid Parameter',
       'url' => '/resource',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks it does the job but `$this->set('_serialize', array(
       'message' => 'Invalid Parameter',
       'url' => '/resource',
    ));` gives `null` at the output.